# Ĉu oni diras "alta kvalito" aŭ "bona kvalito"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Estas iel idiomaĵo mi supozas, kaj mi imagas ke varias inter lingvoj. Ĉu oni diras "alta" aŭ "bona" pri kvalitoj esperantlingve?

Comment: Vi tuŝas interesegan demandon jene! Kiel ekz-e kvalito povas esti ”alta” – ĝi ja ne estas monto… Mi povas rekomendi la jam klasikan libron ”Metaphors We Live By” (Metaforoj laŭ kiuj ni vivas) de George Lakoff kaj Mark Johnson. (Ĉu mi eĉ povus ”varme rekomendi”, eĉ se rekomendo ne estas fajro?) http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/M/bo3637992.html

Answer (score 6):

Oni diras ambaŭ. Alta kvalito = bona kvalito. Ankaŭ eblas diri ke io havas bonajn kvalitojn. "Altkvalita" kaj "bonkvalita" estas oftaj esprimoj.